# How do you access a removable device from the command line?

Tags: macos, mac, command-line

I have a file called `list.txt` on a USB stick that I want to edit using VI. I can't `cd` to the usb stick. It appears on the desktop as ESXI. When I run `diskutil list` it shows up as

```
/dev/disk2
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            ESXI-5.5.0-20140302... *342.5 MB   disk2
```

I can access the device through finder so I think it's already mounted.

Answer (score 4):

Disks may show up on the desktop, but they're not mounted there. They're actually mounted under `/Volumes`.

Related tip: Drag any file or folder from Finder to a Terminal window, and the full path to that file will be entered in the Terminal for you.

Comment: What I usually do is type "cd " in terminal, then find the file volume in the finder and drag it onto the terminal window. That gives you a CD command that will move to the selected volume. It would be very simple to create a drag-and-drop application that would put the path to any volume/folder/file int the clipboard. I've often thought about doing so. (There are applications like TotalFinder that have a "copy path" menu item that does exactly that. TotalFinder seems to make my finder rather unstable, however.)